# When archiving app, Xcode thinks my Icon@2x.png is meant for iPad and not iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have these icons in my resources folder:

- **Icon.png** - 57x57
- **Icon@2x.png** - 114x114
- **Icon-72.png** - 72x72

According to all the [articles out there about supporting various resolutions](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=840/), I believe my app should support older iPhones, iPhone 4, and iPad. However when I archive my app to prepare it for launch, I get this error:

[image: ipad icon]

Isn't Icon@2x.png meant for iPhone 4? Why is it trying to use it for iPad?

Comment: Which Xcode are you using?  I do believe that Xcode4 has these nice UI elements where you can drag the icons of your choice to the correct places and it will rename them to exactly what you need (and possibly modify the .plist file to reflect that as well).

Comment: I have both Xcode 3 and 4. I am just starting to use 4 today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html
I guess yours is iPad App. Icon-72.png is needed. Icon.png and Icon@2x.png is not needed.

Comment: I'm submitting mine as a universal app which needs all 3 icons.

Comment: then, might be xCode Tool issue... Good luck

Comment: I fixed it by adding all my icons to info.plist's as suggested in that article.